# DataGridView - Ordenar coluna através de um botão

Tags: vb.net

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de ordernar uma coluna, de um datagridview, ao clicar em um botão no form depois do DataGridView ja estar populado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível fazer um `Sort` a colunas depois de fazer o `Binding` desta forma:

```
DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns("Name"), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

De qualquer forma é recomendável, se a informação da grelha vier de uma consulta **SQL**, ordenar os registos antes de popular a grelha.

Comment: Bom dia, a informação da grelha vem de uma consulta sql. 
Implantei o exemplo que vc me passou e funcionou aparentemente sem problemas na ordenação da coluna proposta após popular o datagridview.
Se possível, me atente aos problemas que poderei ter.

Comment: O exemplo que indiquei funciona, mas referi a questão da ordenação diretamente na consulta SQL por uma questão de _performance_, porque ordenar a informação que já está na grelha pode demorar bem mais do que na própria consulta SQL. Claro que isto torna-se mais visível com quantidades grandes de informação.

Comment: Valeu João Martins. Sou novato aqui, por favor me informe como posso dar o tópico como encerrado e passar para o site a ajuda que me proporcionou. Um abraço

Comment: Se a resposta o ajudou, então pf confirme-a como correta (um visto de cor cinzenta abaixo da minha resposta, se não estou em erro) e faça um voto positivo na resposta (se tiver reputação para o fazer). Obrigado! Tem aqui informação como aceitar uma resposta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work